# passive vs zu + inf in double infinitive differences:

Tags: infinitive, passive

I'm having trouble with:

> "Damit sind sie zu schwer, als **dass sie** bislang in irgendeinem
>   Experiment **hätten beobachtet werden können**, doch es besteht die
>   Hoffnung, dass solche Teilchen bald im Large Hadron Collider, einem
>   großen Teilchenbeschleuniger in Genf, erzeugt werden."

-Hawking

> That is too heavy for such particles to have been seen in any
>   experiments to date,

Could you say "gekönnt hätten, zu beobachten" 
or  "beobachtet werden haben könnte"
and if so how would the meaning differ?

Also why is it "als **dass sie**" and not "als diejenigen die"?

Comment: that was a fast down vote. Care to comment downvoter?

Comment: I have no real explanation why your quote is fully correct, can only say: "als diejenigen, die" does not fit at all in given sentence. *Als dass* is a quite common phrase, similar to *weswegen* ("Damit sind sie zu schwer, weswegen sie bislang nicht in... .")

Comment: Note that it would be better to use a semicolon here: „Damit sind sie zu schwer, als dass sie bislang in irgendeinem Experiment hätten beobachtet werden können; doch es besteht die Hoffnung, dass solche Teilchen bald im Large Hadron Collider, einem großen Teilchenbeschleuniger in Genf, erzeugt werden.“

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your seem to confuse the pronoun *das* and the subordinating conjunction *dass*. As a conjunction, *(als) dass* can never be replaced by a pronoun, such as *die*. Removing the conjunction gets us a main clause:

> Sie (=die Teilchen) hätten<sub>1</sub> beobachtet<sub>4</sub> werden<sub>3</sub> können<sub>2</sub>.
>   *They could have been observed*.

*Hätten können* is the subjunctive of the past; it is needed because the form *könnte*, although derived from past *konnte*, refers to the present. Removing the past gets rid of *hätten* and yields:

> Sie könnten<sub>1</sub> beobachtet<sub>3</sub> werden<sub>2</sub>.
>   *They could be observed*.

Getting rid of the passive:

> Man könnte<sub>1</sub> sie beobachten<sub>2</sub>.
>   *One could observe them.*

To explain *als dass*, let's look at the translation of a simpler English example:

> *The sofa is too heavy for one person to carry alone.*
>   Das Sofa ist zu schwer, als dass es eine Person allein tragen<sub>2</sub> könnte<sub>1</sub>.

German seems a lot less elegant than English here. In subordinate clauses with *als dass*, a subjunctive (such as *könnte*, or in the past, *hätte können*) is required ([irrealis mood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrealis_mood)); also, where English allows us to simply use *carry*, German pedantically demands *tragen können*, *to be able to carry*. Maybe think of English:

> *The sofa is too heavy. One person **would not be able to carry** it alone.*

with *would be able* corresponding to *könnte* (or *would have been able* corresponding to *hätte können*).

Answer (score 0):

> Damit sind sie zu schwer, als dass sie bislang in irgendeinem Experiment **hätten beobachtet werden können.**

This is a *Konjunktiv II Perfekt Passiv Modal* expression. One of the strangest and heaviest things out there in the wild. Mind the unusual placement of *hätten* — it's required that way.

In general it is possible to replace a *dass* introduced dependent clause by an infinitive clause if the subject is the same as in the main clause. This is the case here. Passive is not special either.

> Er mag es, dass er gewinnt. — Er mag es, zu gewinnen.
>
> Sie mag es, dass sie verwöhnt wird. — Sie mag es, verwöhnt zu werden.

Your example features *als dass* however, and to make it more complicated, this may be shortened to *dass* as well, so it's not easy to spot this is a special case. You cannot put this as an infinitive clause, you merily can put it as an active clause using an infinitive expression.

> Damit sind sie zu schwer, (als) dass sie bislang in irgendeinem Experiment **zu beobachten gewesen** wären.

The expression *es ist zu …* means the same as *es kann/soll/muss/darf … werden*. This is a special feature of the modals. The verb *sein* (wären) implies *können* for pure semantic reasons. The other *sein* (gewesen) is there for the Perfekt.